# Canceled pthread, but not PTHREAD_CANCELED?

Tags: c, pthreads

After canceling a bunch of identical (same function) pthreads with `pthread_cancel()`, I wait on them to stop and collect exit codes :

```
for(j = oldest; j < thCnt ; j++){
  pthread_join(thT[j], &ret); rc = (int)(intptr_t) ret;
}
```

Most threads end up with `ret == PTHREAD_CANCELED`, but one of them does not, and its rc is 115390242 (always the same value, even though the "eccentric" thread may change). From the million printfs I  used to trace this in detail, I'm pretty sure they all caught the `pthread_testcancel()`, so why does one of them not end up with `ret == PTHREAD_CANCELED` ?
Anyone suffered a similar oddity ?

I'm under Linux, using `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` threads.

Comment: Is it possible one of your threads is returning before being cancelled and `115390242` is its return value?

Comment: As I said, I have printfs everywhere, and I'm sure the thread ends in a testcancel(). The only `pthread_exit(&err)`s in the thread routine are called with a variable `err` that only gets values 0 or 1. All lines mentioning `err` either assign it a value of 0, or a 1.

Comment: Is `pthread_join` always returning 0?